# softlayer local Load Balancer manage API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

after customer order local load balancer in softlayer control, customer act a few action for management (Add Group, Add Service, Cancel Load balancer) and then save configuration in control.

i can get detail infomation of load balancer using VirtualIpAddress getObject(id) method but i don't know how to update(save) my changed configuraitons using API?

i was attached screen shot of softlayer control's
which api is available for management of Load balancer?

[Local Load Balancer Detail of control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WN0Ze.png)

Answer (score 0):

well you just need the [editObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/e) method.

```
"""
Add a new service group.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Routing_Type
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Routing_Type/getAllObjects
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Routing_Method
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Routing_Method/getAllObjects

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

loadBalancerId = 79945

# The new allocation value for the service groups.
# The sum of the allocation of all your services group must be 100.
# If you add a new service group it is required to change the allocation
# value of the previous service groups into the load balancer.
# note: the last value is for the new service group you wish to add.
newAllocations = [40, 20, 20, 10, 10]

# The port must unique among the service groups into the load balancer
port = 4040

notes = 'my group note'

method = 'Shortest Response'

group = 'HTTP'

timeout = ""

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
loadBalancerService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress']
groupService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Routing_Type']
methodService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Routing_Method']
objectMask = "mask[virtualServers[serviceGroups]]"
groupFilter = {"name": {"operation": group}}
methodFilter = {"name": {"operation": method}}

try:
    group = groupService.getAllObjects(filter=groupFilter)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the group. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

try:
    method = methodService.getAllObjects(filter=methodFilter)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the method. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

try:
    virtualServer = {
        'port': port,
        'serviceGroups': [
            {
                'routingMethodId': group[0]['id'],
                'routingTypeId': method[0]['id'],
                'notes': notes,
                'timeout': timeout
            }
        ]
    }
    loadBalancer = loadBalancerService.getObject(id=loadBalancerId, mask=objectMask)
    result = loadBalancerService.editObject(loadBalancer, id=loadBalancerId)
    if 'virtualServers' not in loadBalancer:
         loadBalancer['virtualServers'] = []
    loadBalancer['virtualServers'].append(virtualServer)
    if len(loadBalancer['virtualServers']) == len(newAllocations):
        for index in range(len(newAllocations)):
            loadBalancer['virtualServers'][index]['allocation'] = newAllocations[index]
        result = loadBalancerService.editObject(loadBalancer, id=loadBalancerId)
        print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
    else:
        print ("Error the number of configured allocations is not the same as the service groups in the load balancer.")
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to add the service group. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

-

```
 """
Add a new service to a service group.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress/editObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Health_Check_Type
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Health_Check_Type/getAllObjects
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress/findByIpv4Address

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

loadBalancerId = 79945

serviceGroupId = 138193

destinationIpAddress = "169.53.15.53"

destinationPort = 40

weight = 10

notes = "my service group note"

enabled = True

healthCheck = "Ping"

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
loadBalancerService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress']
healthService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Health_Check_Type']
ipService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Subnet_IpAddress']
heaqlthFilter = {"name": {"operation": healthCheck}}
objectMask = "mask[sslActiveFlag, notes, sslEnabledFlag, loadBalancerHardware[hostname,datacenterName,location,locationPathString], ipAddress, virtualServers[notes,port,id,allocation,serviceGroups[services[groupReferences[weight],healthChecks[type[id,name],attributes],ipAddress[id,ipAddress]],routingMethod,routingType]]]"

try:
    healthCheck = healthService.getAllObjects(filter=heaqlthFilter)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the health check. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

try:
    destinationIpAddress = ipService.findByIpv4Address(destinationIpAddress)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the IP address. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

try:
    loadBalancer = loadBalancerService.getObject(id=loadBalancerId, mask=objectMask)
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to get the load balancer. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)

serviceGroup = {}
for i in range(len(loadBalancer['virtualServers'])):
    for j in range(len(loadBalancer['virtualServers'][i]['serviceGroups'])):
        if loadBalancer['virtualServers'][i]['serviceGroups'][j]['id'] == serviceGroupId:
            serviceGroup = loadBalancer['virtualServers'][i]['serviceGroups'][j]
            break

if 'id' not in serviceGroup:
    print("Unable to get the service group id: " + str(serviceGroupId) + " in the load balancer")
else:
    newService = {}
    newService['enabled'] = enabled
    newService['groupReferences'] = []
    groupReferences = {}
    groupReferences['weight'] = weight
    newService['groupReferences'].append(groupReferences)
    newService['healthChecks'] = []
    healthChecks = {}
    healthChecks['healthCheckTypeId'] = healthCheck[0]['id']
    newService['healthChecks'].append(healthChecks)
    newService['ipAddressId'] = destinationIpAddress['id']
    newService['port'] = destinationPort
    newService['notes'] = notes
    loadBalancer['virtualServers'][i]['serviceGroups'][j]['services'].append(newService)
    try:
        result = loadBalancerService.editObject(loadBalancer, id=loadBalancerId)
        print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
    except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
        print("Unable to add the service to the service group. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

-

```
"""
Cancel load balancer.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request/createObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

loadBalancerId = 109225

immediateCancellationFlag = True

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
loadBalancerService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress']
cancellationService = client['SoftLayer_Billing_Item_Cancellation_Request']

objectMask = "mask[accountId, dedicatedFlag,dedicatedBillingItem[id],billingItem[id]]"

try:
    loadBalancer = loadBalancerService.getObject(id=loadBalancerId, mask=objectMask)
    billingItemId = 0
    if loadBalancer['dedicatedFlag']:
        billingItemId = loadBalancer['dedicatedBillingItem']['id']
    else:
        billingItemId = loadBalancer['billingItem']['id']
    cancelTemplate = {
        'accountId': loadBalancer['accountId'],
        'items': [
            {
                'billingItemId': billingItemId,
                'immediateCancellationFlag': immediateCancellationFlag
            }
        ]
    }
    result = cancellationService.createObject(cancelTemplate)
    print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to cancel the load balancer. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

-

```
"""
Remove a service group from a load balancer.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualServer
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualServer/
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualServer/deleteObject

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The virtual server which contains the service group to delete.
virtualServerId = 193563

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
virtualService = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_VirtualServer']

try:
    result = virtualService.deleteObject(id=virtualServerId)
    print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to remove the service group. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

-

```
"""
Remove a service from a load balancer.

Important manual pages:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Service
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Service/deleteObject
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Service

License: http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/License
Author: SoftLayer Technologies, Inc. <sldn@softlayer.com>
"""

import SoftLayer
import json

# Your SoftLayer API username and key.
USERNAME = 'set me'
API_KEY = 'set me'

# The service id to delete.
serviceId = 367111

client = SoftLayer.Client(username=USERNAME, api_key=API_KEY)
service = client['SoftLayer_Network_Application_Delivery_Controller_LoadBalancer_Service']

try:
    result = service.deleteObject(id=serviceId)
    print(json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=2, separators=(',', ': ')))
except SoftLayer.SoftLayerAPIError as e:
    print("Unable to remove the service. faultCode=%s, faultString=%s" % (e.faultCode, e.faultString))
    exit(1)
```

Regards

Comment: really thanks.. it is my answer !! additionally, how to upgrade ? from 250 VIP to 500 VIP using api

Comment: i'm done using SoftLayer_Network_LoadBalancer_VirtualIpAddress::upgradeConnectionLimit api thanks...